# Seekbar progress animation

Tags: android, animation, android-seekbar

I'm trying to animate the seekbar progress. It works fine when the progress update is not from user(which is what I want) but when the user drags the seekbar, I want the animation to stop. Right now what happens is when user drags the seekbar, the seekbar progress animates and there is delay because of the animation. I hope you guys get what I'm trying to say. I only want the animation when the input is not from user else animate.

Code:

```
  circularSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

            circularSeekBar.setEnabled(true);


            if(fromUser) {

                int seekprogress = (int) circularSeekBar.getProgress();

                Intent io = new Intent(ConstantsForBroadCast.ACTION_PLAY_SEEKBAR);
                io.putExtra("Progress", seekprogress);
                getActivity().sendBroadcast(io);

            }

        }




 public  void Handler(final MediaPlayer mp){


    currentSongLength= mp.getDuration();



    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    if((Activity)getActivity()!=null) {
        ((Activity) getActivity()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                circularSeekBar.setMax((int) currentSongLength / 1000);
                int mCurrentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
                ObjectAnimator animation1 = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(circularSeekBar,"progress", mCurrentPosition);
                animation1.setDuration(1000); // 0.5 second
                animation1.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
                animation1.start();
                circularSeekBar.clearAnimation();

                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);


            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: I assume that you are already using `CustomSeekbar` . So so already have control on thumb drag so not animate when thumb drag animate only using `setProgress()`.

Comment: Actually I have the default seekbar from android

Comment: try to make use of `onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)` and `onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)` of `SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener`.

Comment: Tried them both, works the first time then as usual